# Desert Island Tools?

Tags: server-room

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Server room survival kit?](https://serverfault.com/questions/2382/server-room-survival-kit)

If you could pick five commands/tools to have with you to admin a system, what would they be?

Comment: What is the difference between this question and "name your favourite ..." (except you name only 5 of them here) ?

Comment: They do not have electricity on desert islands.

Comment: @d03boy - actually, they may have electricity - they just don't have people.

Answer (score 2):

- bash
- cat

Everything else is just window dressing ;-)

Answer (score 2):

- vim
- perl
- knife
- swimming shorts / hawaiian shirt
- Claudia Schiffer

Comment: +1 - Good call on the shorts / shirt. I also would have accepted "satellite internet terminal" or "Summer Glau"

Comment: I'll diff manually.

Answer (score 1):

- vim
- patch
- diff
- sponge
- sed

Answer (score 1):

debug.com - If you can't do everything with debug, well, I guess you're probably getting real work done.

Answer (score 1):

- perl
- apt-get
- du
- vim
- top

Answer (score 1):

- perl
- lsof
- find
- grep
- telnet

Answer (score 1):

For a windows box:

1. powershell
2. process explorer
3. telnet
4. notepad
5. mmc

Answer (score 1):

In a *nix world, I'd have to pick:

- vim
- curl
- perl
- bash
- apache

Answer (score 0):

In the Windows world:

- Sysinternals Process Explorer
- grep (yes, on Windows)
- [WinRAR](http://www.rarlab.com/rar_archiver.htm)
- [Console2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/)
- My coffee maker

Answer (score 0):

Depends hugely on the system, but for a general Windows one.

- Firefox
- Wireshark
- Process Explorer
- Netcat
- Cain

Answer (score 0):

- lsof
- ps
- ls
- vi
- ip

Answer (score 0):

- Debian netinst CD
- network connection

That's how I setup all my servers anyway...

Answer (score 0):

- aptitude
- autotools
- vim
- gcc
- curl

Answer (score 0):

rsync
lsof
vim
find
ssh

Answer (score 0):

- sh
- vim
- ssh
- git
- awk

Interaction, editing, communication, control, automation... what else could you need?